# How to assign specific color to rectangular region depend on an integer output in python and show that rectangular region on desktop?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar

[image]I am calculating some integer value in range of zero to ten based on some calculations; and i am also getting output in terminal; but i am unable to show a rectangular strip on desktop based on output value. Such that, strip color changes from black to white as output changes from zero to ten.
And I am not interested in showing any image other than a color strip.
Thank you in advance.

I have tried using 'colorbar' function from 'matplotlib', but says "no mappable was found for this color creation and so on.

```
# for graphing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, colorbar
x = 0
y = x*x - x
plt.colorbar()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 6, in 
    plt.colorbar()
  File "/home/abhihsek/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2093, in colorbar
    raise RuntimeError('No mappable was found to use for colorbar '
RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).

I am expecting a rectangular strip on right side of my screen with specific color as mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly you are trying to plot. Do you just want to plot a single color that fills the figure? I'm not sure colorbar is what you want.

Comment: Actually, i am trying to indicate my output value, in the form of color on desktop. I am expecting, a way to draw a rectangular strip like indicator on my screen.

Comment: i have just changed my title. I hope, it makes clear, what i am asking.

Comment: Are you trying to plot anything else? By screen do you actually mean screen? or figure? And what exactly is this "output value". And how is it being updated and when should this be reflected in your "color bar"? It would be helpful if you could clarify your question a bit more.

Comment: Thank you Sir, i have written a program, and i am getting output in my terminal after running my program. The output value is an integer in range from zero to ten. And i want my output shown on my desktop screen as a notification, in the form of color. Example, when output of my program is zero, it should show black color, when output is five, it should show some lighter color and at last white color should be shown when output value is 10. These color should be shown in a small rectangular area as shown in figure. I hope sir, u understand, what I mean to say. Thank you again.

Comment: A colorbar shows all the colors from the colormap. If you want a rectangle in a specific color use `plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1, color=<your color>))`